# High Memory (~8GB) pay per compute time server requirement

Tags: php, amazon-aws, python, google-compute

I'm looking for an AWS Lambda replacement in order to generate map tile images in parallel. Unfortunately Lambda has a memory limit of 1.5GB and some of my source images sizes are 80MB, using around 7 GB in memory at it's peak loading into memory before starting cropping actions into lots of smaller tiles.

I'm really looking for something that only charges me for the compute time since I'll only be using around 20 hours of compute time a month max, and it needs to be easy to startup and shutdown programmatically (preferably automatically like AWS Lambda).

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Sorry but recommendations on services, software, resources and websites are considered off-topic on Pro Webmasters.